# Bootstrap Glyphicon as button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Say I wanted to use a glyphicon as a submit button for a form. How would I go about doing this?

To elaborate, I want no 'visible' elements of a traditional button. Just a glyphicon, as it would appear normally in text.

I have tried using `<button>` and `<input type='button'>` with the glyphicon classes, and (as one would expect), no luck.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/cCZfQ/ ?

Comment: @koala_dev Yes! Didn't know about the btn-link class. Feel free to add

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `.btn-link` class to have a button appear as a text link:

```
<form>
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</button>
</form>
```

See this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/cCZfQ/)**

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Did not know about this class. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Kye No problem, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted to let the community know your issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</button>
```

[Give this a read](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use)

Comment: I am still given the button 'look'.

Comment: Remove `btn-default` then, or create your own styles.

Comment: Ah forget that, @koala_dev got it